# couple questions about custom arrayadapter

Tags: android, sqlite, android-arrayadapter

so im a little confused here....

i have code that takes info from my sqlite database and populates a list, then shows the list using the standard array adapter. what i want to do is have it so that in this list, the row color is green if the "completed" table row value is "yes"

heres my db structure for the table being used:

```
    String CREATE_ACHIEVEMENTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE achievements ("
             + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
             + "name VARCHAR,"
             + "type VARCHAR,"
             + "value VARCHAR,"
             + "completed VARCHAR"
             + ")";
```

heres my code that gets the list from the db:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAchievements(Context context) {
    ArrayList<String> achievementList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM achievements ORDER BY id asc";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                if (cursor.getString(4).equals("yes")) {
                    achievementList.add(cursor.getString(1)+" (completed)");
                }
                else {
                    achievementList.add(cursor.getString(1));
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    else {
        achievementList.add(context.getResources().getString(R.string.na));
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return achievementList;
}
```

heres my custom arrayadapter:

```
public class AchievementAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public AchievementAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.achievements, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.achievement_item, parent, false);
        }

        return row;
    }
}
```

i really have no clue where to go from here. this is my first android app and i have learned a LOT, but i cant seem to figure out how to achieve this simple thing in regards to custom arrayadapters....all the tutorials i find contain a bunch of features that i dont want. all im trying to do is make the text color of the list item green if its "completed" table value is "yes"...

Comment: whats with all the downvotes lately? do people just come and downvote questions without offering any explanation why or help on this website now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I recommend using a cursorAdapter instead of an arrayAdapter. With a cursor adapter you will have a pointer to the DB so you can get all of the information from there.

If you do that... your code for the adapter should look something like this.

```
private class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("completed").equals("yes")){
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.NAMEOFTEXTVIEW);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context arg0, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.achievement_item, parent, false);
        return row;
    }
}
```

and you create the adapter with:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
mAdapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this, cursor);
```

Having said all that... if you want to use the arrayAdapter and just change the textview,
in getView:

```
String item = (String) getItem(position);
if(item.contains("(completed)"){
    TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.NAMEOFTEXTVIEW);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

I should note that with a cursorAdapter you should keep the cursor open, and close it in onStop (reopen it in onRestart)

Comment: thank you so much i didnt even know about cursoradapter. very helpful. thanks for trying to help and not just downvoting me like everyone else seems to be doing.